# Insert into array in reverse while iterating forward

Tags: javascript, performance, array

So currently I have this function:

```
function loadPath(chunkSize, dataSize, depth, index) {
  let path = []
  let i = 0
  while (i < depth) {
    path.unshift(index % chunkSize)
    index = Math.floor(index / chunkSize)
    i++
  }
  return path
}
```

I would now like to pass in `path` as a variable from an object pool of short path arrays. So for example:

```
function loadPath(path, chunkSize, dataSize, depth, index) {
  
}

let path = new Array(3)
loadPath(path, 5, 100, 3, 41)
console.log(path) // 1, 3, 1
loadPath(path, 5, 100, 3, 50)
console.log(path) // ...
```

The question is, how can I do that without using push/unshift or reverse operations on the array? Basically just treating the array as a static block of memory, while at the same time not adding any unnecessary operations.

```
function loadPath(path, chunkSize, dataSize, depth, index) {
  let i = 0
  let x = depth - 1
  while (i < depth) {
    path[x] = index % chunkSize
    index = Math.floor(index / chunkSize)
    i++
    x--
  }
}
```

My question is, can this be done with any fewer temp variables? Some magic along the lines of this?

```
function loadPath(path, chunkSize, dataSize, depth, index) {
  let i = 0
  while (i < depth) {
    // something tricky perhaps here?
    // since x and i have a reciprocal relationship...
    // somehow fill it in backwards...
    path[depth - i] = index % chunkSize
    index = Math.floor(index / chunkSize)
    i++
  }
}
```

Or perhaps there is another way entirely to write this algorithm to be in as few steps and operations and temp variables as possible.

Could also use this [`floor` implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/289/shortest-floor-function) integrated somehow if it helps :)

```
function floor(n) {
  return ~~n - (~~n > n)
}
```

Comment: Your title short be short and concise while explaining what your code does.

Comment: You should be able to calculate the number of loops you need to do, so you can create an empty array of that size and fill it backwards. If I'm not mistaken it should be `Math.log(chunkSize) / Math.log(index)` (rounded up).

Comment: Would you consider using `concat`?

Comment: How about: `path[depth - i - 1] = index % chunkSize` - no need for `x`.

Comment: What is this mysterious `index` and what is/why are you not using `dataSize`?

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate question...
The same answer from your previous similar question:
`function recBucket(number, size) {
  if(number<size) return [number];
  else {
    var whole=Math.floor(number/size);
    return [recBucket(whole, size), number-whole*size].flat();
  }
};`
Use: `recBucket(index, chunkSize)`.
Answer: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/249779/227994
Question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249526/algorithm-to-find-bucket-and-item-indices-from-power-of-two-bins

Comment: If `chunkSize` is less than 11, `41` in your example, you can use: `(41).toString(5).split("")`...

Comment: @iAmOren I'm not a fan of the string hacky solutions tbh, converting to string and splitting and such, I like to keep it pure as possible haha.

Comment: Does `path[depth - i - 1] = index % chunkSize` work??

Comment: Seems to wotk:
`depth=3;
path=Array(depth);
chunkSize=5;
index=41;
for(i=0;i<depth;i++) {
  path[depth - i - 1] = index % chunkSize;
  index=Math.floor(index/chunkSize);
};
console.log(path);`
returns `[1, 3, 1]`.

Comment: The down side is that you have to declare the Array in advance;
How about just adding in order, then reversing the array?
Adding in order:
`path=[]; for..... path[path.length]=...`.
If you don't want to use `.reverse`, then:
`depth=3; //path.length
for(i=0;i<(depth-1)/2;i++) [a[i], a[depth-i-1]] = [a[depth-i-1], a[i]];`.

Comment: Once we figure out what's best for your need, I'll transform that into an answer.
Meanwhile, can you accept and select my current answer?

Comment: Ok, see my new answer.
Question: What do you want to do if `index` >= `chunkSize`^3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try the other way:

```js
function loadPath(path, chunkSize, dataSize, depth, index) {
  for(var i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
    path[depth - i - 1] = index % chunkSize;
    index = Math.floor(index / chunkSize);
  };
};

var path = Array(3);
console.log("loadPath(path, 5, 100, 3, 41)");
loadPath(path, 5, 100, 3, 41);
console.log(path);
console.log("loadPath(path, 5, 100, 3, 50)");
loadPath(path, 5, 100, 3, 50);
console.log(path);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

What do you want to do if `index` >= `chunkSize`^3?

Comment: Thank you for the accept!
Up-vote, please?!? :)
Still: What do you want to do if `index` >= `chunkSize`^3?

Comment: I can handle that outside of the function no problem.

Comment: Great!
Thanks for the up-vote.
I still have no clue as to what you are doing... :)

Comment: I am working on a [vm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64071543/if-you-can-build-the-call-stack-on-top-of-a-more-primitive-virtual-machine) and this is an aspect of the memory allocation part.

Comment: Interesting!
So, the `path` will tell which "floor", which "apartment", and which "room" there is data of (up to) `dataSize` part of the data - all pointed to with the assistance of `index`?
And there are up to `chunkSize`^3 such "rooms", with maximum storage capacity of `chunkSize`^3 * `dataSize` * `dataSize`'s unit size?

Comment: Haha no not like that, but interesting concept I never thought of that! Basically it's going to chunk arrays into small chunks to optimize memory layout and prevent fragmentation ideally.

Comment: What do you think of this:
`path2 = (chunkSize, dataSize, depth, index,
  chunkSize2 = chunkSize * chunkSize,
  p2 = Math.floor(index / chunkSize2),
  p1 = Math.floor((index - p2 * chunkSize2) / chunkSize),
  p0 = index - p2 * chunkSize2 - p1 * chunkSize
) => [p2 ,p1 ,p0];`
?

Comment: Without a declaration for `i` using `var` or `let` a global variable would be created, which won't lead to an error but [typically frowned upon](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148109/244085)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ, correct!  Fixed.
When I test bits of code I omit the `var`s - this time I forgot to add it - good eye!

Answer (score 0):

Same [Answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/249779/227994) to your own same/similar [Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249526/algorithm-to-find-bucket-and-item-indices-from-power-of-two-bins)...
Hint: accept and up-vote both... :)

```js
function recBucket(number, size) {
  if(number<size) return [number];
  else {
    var whole=Math.floor(number/size);
    return [recBucket(whole, size), number-whole*size].flat();
  }
};

function loadPath(chunkSize, dataSize, depth, index) {
  return recBucket(index, chunkSize);
};

console.log(loadPath(5, 100, 3, 41));
console.log(loadPath(5, 100, 3, 50));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `.flat` feels a  feels a bit hacky, just hiding implementation details to make things appear shorter.

Comment: Also recursion is less-than ideal.